# Nested div size with offset in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:pink;">
    <p>
    test
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" style="background-color:green;">
      <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:red;">
      <p>
      red
      </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:blue;">
      <p>
      blue
      </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <p>
        yellow
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b7f5ob1g/1/

I created this layout, but i dont understand the sizing.

The outer div with the id="wrapper" got a col size from 8, offset from 2 (which means it gets pulled to the right by 2 cols, so there is 2 cols free space on the right.

So in total i have 8 cols for content.

Now with the 3 inner divs in my understanding i tried to size the columns

```
div1: col size 6
div2: col size 1
div3: col size 1
```

So it gets summed up to 8. But to then its too small, I have to sum it up to 12.

Like div1:8, div2:2, div3:2.

Do I have to count in such nested divs to 12 cols or can you explain this situation to me please?

Comment: You should have additional `row` elements around your “inner” columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Bootstrap grid system](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/) all col-* elements have to be wrapped in a `.row` element. Inside each `.row` you have 12 columns, no matter how big/small is the parent column container. That said, your html should look like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:pink;">
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" style="background-color:green;" id="wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:red;">
          <p>red</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:blue;">
          <p>blue</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:yellow;">
          <p>yellow</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b7f5ob1g/2/)

Comment: After your explanation i understand what the bootstrap documentation means about nesting columns. Thank you!